# apache location alias vs nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

I have followed this tutorial on using Let's Encrypt with Kerio Mailserver: https://irulan.net/using-lets-encrypt-with-kerio-connect

This works fine, but I feel more comfortable using Apache. I was wondering what is the Apache counterpart of the following:

```
location /.well-known {
    alias /var/www/mail/.well-known;
}
```

And is this (nginx):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass       https://localhost:8843;
    proxy_set_header Host                 $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Remote-Port        $remote_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
    proxy_redirect  off;
}
```

the same as this (apache):

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8843
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8843
```

???

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
ServerName fqdn.ext

<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/

        Alias "/.well-known" "/var/www/mail/.well-known"

        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/fqdn.ext/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/fqdn.ext/privkey.pem
        SSLCompression Off
        SSLSessionTickets Off
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE$
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```